# Is it possible to use one certificate with aliases for MongoDB cluster?

Tags: mongodb, certificate, tls-1.2

I currently configure a MongoDB cluster to use TLS certificate.

It could be far more easier to deploy, one certificate with aliases accross all cluster, instead of one certificate per node. But there is no mention of this in documentation, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, yes : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/#x-509

> Either the Common Name (CN) or one of the Subject Alternative Name
>   (SAN) entries must match the hostname of the server, used by the other
>   members of the cluster.
>
> For example, the certificates for a cluster could have the following
>   subjects: subject= CN=,OU=Dept1,O=MongoDB,ST=NY,C=US
>   subject= CN=,OU=Dept1,O=MongoDB,ST=NY,C=US subject=
>   CN=,OU=Dept1,O=MongoDB,ST=NY,C=US